# Detect if a C compiler supports __typeof and/or decltype

Tags: embedded, c-preprocessor, typeof, decltype

The uthash library (which I maintain) currently uses this snippet to define a macro `DECLTYPE(x)` which expands to a C-style cast to `x`'s type, or else to define `NO_DECLTYPE`:

```
/* These macros use decltype or the earlier __typeof GNU extension.
   As decltype is only available in newer compilers (VS2010 or gcc 4.3+
   when compiling c++ source) this code uses whatever method is needed
   or, for VS2008 where neither is available, uses casting workarounds. */
#if defined(_MSC_VER)
  #if _MSC_VER >= 1600 && defined(__cplusplus)
    /* VS2010 or newer in C++ mode */
    #define DECLTYPE(x) (decltype(x))
  #else
    /* VS2008 or older (or VS2010 in C mode) */
    #define NO_DECLTYPE
  #endif
#elif defined(__BORLANDC__) || defined(__ICCARM__) || defined(__LCC__) || defined(__WATCOMC__)
  #define NO_DECLTYPE
#else
  /* GNU, Sun and other compilers */
  #define DECLTYPE(x) (__typeof(x))
#endif
```

I imagine this could be cleaned up a lot these days, but I don't want to break any old or obscure compilers if I can help it. I'm thinking of doing something like this:

```
#if defined(__cplusplus) && (__cpp_decltype >= 200707L || _MSC_VER >= 1600)
  #define DECLTYPE(x) (decltype(x))
#elif defined(__MCST__) || defined(__GNUC__) || defined(__clang__) || defined(__chibicc__)
  /* chibicc supports __typeof__ but not __typeof */
  #define DECLTYPE(x) (__typeof__(x))
#else
  #define NO_DECLTYPE
#endif
```

Wondering if anyone can point to any other projects that have tackled this problem (maybe I can copy their solution); or improve this solution; or preemptively point out compilers for which it would fail. I propose to keep this question up-to-date by periodically merging improvements below:

### Best solution to date

```
#if defined(__cplusplus) && (__cpp_decltype >= 200707L || _MSC_VER >= 1600)
  #define DECLTYPE(x) (decltype(x))
#elif defined(__MCST__) || defined(__GNUC__) || defined(__clang__) || defined(__chibicc__)
  /* chibicc supports __typeof__ but not __typeof */
  #define DECLTYPE(x) (__typeof__(x))
#else
  #define NO_DECLTYPE
#endif
```

Comment: Won't solve your problem with backwards compatibility, but `typeof` has been proposed to get added to the C23 standard, [see this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/23). I have no idea how much consensus there is in the committee regarding it though.

Comment: I see my fav project - https://github.com/nemequ/hedley/blob/master/hedley.h#L1769 - doesn't come with this detection, but the detection there handles already many compielrs. I think you could make a PR there.

Comment: @lundin: it's basically been accepted, along with `typeof_unqual` (originally proposed as `remove_quals`); you'll find it in the [current draft](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n3047.pdf). Also `auto`, although as [JeanHeyd Meneide](https://thephd.dev/c23-is-coming-here-is-what-is-on-the-menu#oh-no-those-evil-committee-people-are-ruining-my-favorite-language%E2%93%A1-with-c-nonsense%E2%93%92) points, with much simpler semantics than C++. And lots more.